# Javascript this keyword

Tags: javascript, this

I am following "you-dont-know-js" book. i have a doubt in the following code:

```
var something = {
    cool: function() {
        this.greeting = "hello";
        this.count = this.count?this.count+1:1;
    }
};

something.cool();
console.log(something.greeting);
console.log(something.count);

var another = {
    cool: function() {
        //something.cool.call(this);
        something.cool()
    }
}

another.cool();
console.log(another.greeting);
console.log(another.count);
```

if another.cool has the following code

```
something.cool()
```

rather than

```
something.cool.call(this);
```

i get the output as undefined for the following console.log

```
console.log(another.greeting);
console.log(another.count);
```

By default , should not the reference to this be "something", and the output as :

```
hello
2
```

Comment: `something.cool()` calls the first `cool()` method with `this` set to `something`, whereas `something.cool.call(this);` calls that `cool()` with `this` set to `another`.

Comment: When you call by something.cool(), this is binding to something, that's why it does not effect the object another. Even when it's called inside the cool function of another.

Comment: In your code, *this* is set by how the function is called, so if you call it with a different *this*, you get a different result.

Comment: nnnnnn---->that i am aware of, what i wanted to know is , when i call something.cool() inside another.cool()......why do i get undefined for both the consoles .....                                                                                                    李骏骁------>so the default binding in this case is not aplied ??? sorry, i am a bit confused                                                                                                         RobG-----> that i am aware of , thanks :)

Comment: When this greeting = "hello" is called on your latter case, the this will refer to something. And you're trying to print by another.greeting. Another's cool won't effect what is doing inside something's call.

Comment: Check out this URL: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: As a general rule, remember that `this` is evaluated at runtime, not where it was defined.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `something.cool();`, whether you call that from the global scope or from within `another.cool`, the keyword `this` in the definition of `something.cool`still refers to the `something` object.

In other words, (and this is the answer to your actual question) where `something.cool();` is called does not change the value of the `this` keyword that is found in the `something.cool` method definition.

When, however, you call `something.cool.call(this)` from within the definition of `another.cool` you're executing `something.cool` as if it were part of the `another` object, because the `this` that you're passing to the call is a reference to the `another` object.

The argument passed to `something.cool.call(this)` is used as the *context* of the method being called. From within the `another.cool` method definition the `this` keyword refers to the `another` object.